# Can I use an ended sound file to transition to a new scene or refresh data in the same scene?

Tags: audio, timer, lua, coronasdk, scene

Lua novice asks:
How do I transition from this...
(a simple example to establish a how-to)...

```
visual = display.newImage( "redCircle.png", 50, 50 ) 

local music = audio.loadStream("sound1.mp3")
    audio.play(music)

audio.stopWithDelay(60000/60)
```

to this, timed by the first sound file ending?

```
visual = display.newImage( "blueCircle.png", 50, 50 ) 

local music = audio.loadStream("sound2.mp3")
audio.play(music)

audio.stopWithDelay(60000/60)
```

Which api should I be experimenting with? I've looked at https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/index.html
       What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a function listener for the first audio file you can look more here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/play.html Below is a sample code I can give you. Note that I did not use `audio.stopWithDelay`

```
--DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
local visual1
local visual2
local music1 
local music2

--LOAD SOUNDS
music1 = audio.loadStream("sound1.mp3")
music2 = audio.loadStream("sound2.mp3")

local function soundIsFinished(event)

    if (event.completed) then

        --PLAY SECOND AUDIO AND HIDE/REMOVE VISUAL 1
        visual1.isVisible = false
        visual2.isVisible = true
        audio.play(music2, {duration = 1000})       

    end

end

--DISPLAY VISUAL1 and play MUSIC1
visual1 = display.newImage("redCircle.png", 50,50)

--AUDIO WILL PLAY FOR 1 SECOND (60000/60) is 1 second
audio.play(music1, { duration=1000, onComplete=soundIsFinshed } )

-- HIDE VISUAL2 FIRST
visual2 = display.newImage("blueCircle.png", 50,50)
visual2.isVisible = false
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a problem with audio.stopWithDelay?

Comment: audio.stopWithDelay() stops the whole channel not the audio handles and as far as the docs example, it does not have a oncomplete listener. You can view it here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/stopWithDelay.html